# Why does the ASCII codes of number characters get written to the file?

Tags: c, binary, ascii, fwrite

I'm writing a binary file with the following code

```
char x[] = "02 00 27 FF FF 92 20";
FILE *ptr_x;
ptr_x=fopen("xx","wb");
fwrite(x, 1, 1, ptr_x);
```

The problem is that if i open the file it is written like this:

```
"30 32 20 30 30 20 32 37 20 46 46 20 46 46 20 39 32 20 32 30"
```

Which is the ASCII representation of the text above.
What i would like to have is a file with exactly those values written in and not the ASCI representation.

Regards,

Solution:

```
uint8_t x[68] = {0x05,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                0x00,0x00,0x00,0x18,0xDA,0x18,0xF1,0x18,
                0xDA,0xF1,0x18,0xF1,0x18,0x00,0x05,0x02,
                0x01,0x14,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x0B,0x00,0x33,
                0x01,0x01,0x04,0x02,0x00,0x27,0xFF,0xFF,
                0x92,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x23,0xFE,0x00,
                0x04,0x02,0x00,0x27,0xFF,0xFF,0x04,0x02,
                0x00,0x23,0xFE,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                0x00,0x00,0x92,0x20};

FILE *ptr_x;
ptr_x=fopen("xx","wb");
fwrite(x, 68, 1, ptr_x);
```

Comment: What do you expect to be written to the file?

Comment: Well `x` is a string, containing (on your system) of ASCII encoded characters. So that's what will be written when you write the raw data of the string.

Comment: Your program writes one single byte to the file. So the file cannot contain `"30 32 20 30 30 20 32 37 20 46 46 20 46 46 20 39 32 20 32 30"` Are you sure the code you posted is the code you are using ?

Comment: Your solution is wrong, should be `unsigned char` or `uint_8`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an array like this: `unsigned char x[] = {0x02, 0x00, 0x27, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x92, 0x20};` or, even better, use `uint8_t` instead of `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fwrite(x, 1, 1, ptr_x);
```

Means "Write the data to that `x` points to to `ptr_x`. That data consists out of `1` element(s) and every element is `1` byte in size."

That's a lie. Your data consists out of 20 bytes. So either the data consists out of 20 elements that are 1 bytes each:

```
fwrite(x, 1, 20, ptr_x);
```

or it consists out of 1 element that is 20 byte in size:

```
fwrite(x, 20, 1, ptr_x);
```

Or more general:

```
fwrite(x, strlen(x), 1, ptr_x);
```